# Add fields into dynamical module use code at behind in sitefinity

Tags: module, sitefinity

In sitefinity, we can add new module (data table) in the backend dashboard , however , i would like to modify the module use script such as edit , create and update a field . I have been searching online , there is no direct answers to it

Answer (score 0):

Are the Admin app extensions what you need perhaps?

https://github.com/Sitefinity/sitefinity-admin-app-extensions